# Finishing the proof: given any subspace, it has a complement

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, proof-writing

The proof is as followed but I was not able to complete it, I hope someone could hit it with a magic stick.

Proof:

> Let $V, U \subset X$ be two subspaces, where $dim(V) = k$, $dim(X)
>  =n$, $k \leq n$
>
> Then let $V = span\{v_1, \cdots, v_k\}$. Find $\{v_{k+1}, \cdots,
>  v_{n}\}$ such that $\{v_1, \cdots, v_{n}\}$ is a basis for $X$. Then
>   $W = span\{v_{k+1}, \cdots, v_{n}\}$ is a complement of $V$

But to complete the proof I need to show that $V \cap W$ = $0$. But it seems to me the construction makes $V, W$ to be disjoint. But yet we know that $V, W$ must contain $0$. How can I formally show that their intersection is $0$?

Comment: As we are taking a linear span, we and up with a vector space. Since a vector space is closed under scalar multiplication, what happens when we multiply an arbitrary vector $v\in V$ with $0$? And $w\in W$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you (really already) know you have a basis, then $\{v_1,\ldots, v_n\}$ are linearly independent. So if $v = \sum_{1}^k \lambda _i v_i$ is in the intersection then also $ v= \sum_{k+1}^n \lambda _i v_i$ and then $$0=\sum_{1}^k \lambda _i v_i - \sum_{k+1}^n \lambda _i v_i$$ which by definition of linear independence implies $\lambda_i=0$ for all $i $ an so $v=0$

Edit: note that this shows both statements: $0$ is in the intersection and it's the only vector in the intersection.

Comment: I think this works very nicely